# php Edit Profile when user is not providing password how to check if its empty

Tags: php, forms, post, submit

I have the form that is for users to edit their profiles:

```
 <div id="page">
   <?php echo message(); ?>
   <?php echo form_errors($errors); ?>

   <h2>Edit Admin: <?php echo htmlentities($admin["username"]); ?></h2>
   <form action="edit_admin.php?usr_serno=<?php echo urlencode($admin["usr_serno"]); ?>"  method="post">
   <p>Username:
   <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo htmlentities($admin["username"]); ?>" />
   </p>
   <p>Password:
   <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
   <?php if (!isset($_GET["password"])

   </p>
   <p>Email:
   <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo htmlentities($admin["email"]); ?>" />
   </p>
   <p>Role:
   <select type="int" name="role_serno">
   <option value="1">Administrator</option>
   <option value="2">User</option>

   </select>
   </p>
   <p>First Name:
   <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo htmlentities($admin["name"]); ?>" />
   </p>
   <p>Last Name:
   <input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo htmlentities($admin["lastname"]); ?>" />
   </p>
   <p>ID:
   <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo htmlentities($admin["id"]); ?>" />
   </p>
   <p>Address:
   <input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo htmlentities($admin["address"]); ?>" />
  </p>
  <p>Postcode:
    <input type="text" name="postcode" value="<?php echo htmlentities($admin["postcode"]); ?>" />
  </p>

  <p>City:
  <select id="city" type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo htmlentities($admin["city"]); ?>">
   <option value="Nicosia">Nicosia</option>
   <option value="Limassol">Limassol</option>
   <option value="Larnaca">Larnaca</option>
   <option value="Paphos">Paphos</option>
   <option value="Other">Other</option>
   </select>
   <input id="other_city" type="text" name="other_city" value="<?php echo htmlentities($admin["city"]); ?>" />
  </p>      
  <p>Telephone:
    <input type="text" name="telephone" value="<?php echo htmlentities($admin["telephone"]); ?>" />
  </p>
  <p>College:
    <input type="text" name="college" value="<?php echo htmlentities($admin["college"]); ?>" />
  </p>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit Admin" />
  </form>
  <br />
  <a href="manage_admins.php">Cancel</a>
  </div>
```

`

And on top of that page i am checking and trying to update the users profile:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$required_fields = array("username","email","role_serno",
"name","lastname","id","telephone","address","college","postcode","city");
validate_presences($required_fields);

$fields_with_max_lengths = array("username" => 30);
validate_max_lengths($fields_with_max_lengths);

if (empty($errors)) {

// Perform Update
//if (!isset ($_POST["password"]))
//$hashed_password = $_GET["password"];
//if (isset ($_POST["password"]))
$id_serno = $admin["usr_serno"];
$username = mysql_prep($_POST["username"]);
$hashed_password = password_encrypt($_POST["password"]);
$email=mysql_prep($_POST["email"]);
$role_serno=mysql_prep($_POST["role_serno"]);
$name=mysql_prep($_POST["name"]);
$lastname=mysql_prep($_POST["lastname"]);
$id=mysql_prep( $_POST["id"]);
$date_create=mysql_prep( $_POST["date_create"]);
$address=mysql_prep( $_POST["address"]);
$postcode=mysql_prep( $_POST["postcode"]);
$city=mysql_prep( $_POST["city"]);
$telephone=mysql_prep( $_POST["telephone"]);
$college=mysql_prep( $_POST["college"]);

$query  = "UPDATE users SET ";
$query .= "username = '{$username}', ";
$query .= "password = '{$hashed_password}', ";
$query .= "email = '{$email}', ";
$query .= "role_serno = '{$role_serno}', ";
$query .= "name = '{$name}', ";
$query .= "lastname = '{$lastname}', ";
$query .= "id = '{$id}', ";
$query .= "address = '{$address}', ";
$query .= "postcode = '{$postcode}', ";
$query .= "city = '{$city}', ";
$query .= "telephone = '{$telephone}', ";
$query .= "college = '{$college}' ";
$query .= "WHERE usr_serno = {$id_serno} ";
$query .= "LIMIT 1";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if ($result && mysqli_affected_rows($connection) == 1) {
  // Success
  $_SESSION["message"] = "Admin updated.";
  redirect_to("manage_admins.php");
} else {
  // Failure
  $_SESSION["message"] = "Admin update failed.";
}

}
} else {
// This is probably a GET request

} // end: if (is set($_POST["submit"]))`
```

the issue comes when the user is posting a form without passing the password in cause then the database is updated with empty password and i have a check not to accept empty passwords at lo-gin page.

Is there a way to avoid and check this.

Please advise cause I am new with developing in php and I am not 100% sure how this is going to be done.

I tried so far to check if post value is empty then pass the current database value without encoding it.. but for some reason the if check doesn't actually do anything

Answer (score 0):

You can add a  client side javascript validation here.
In case of server side 
check

```
if(empty($_POST['password']))
{
    // whatever you want to ask and do
}
```

Comment: The hashed password is never empty cause I am adding things on the password to encrypt better.

Comment: So even if the user passes an empty string the database will keep smth the issue is that after the decryption during the login it will prompt me that this is an empty string for password and it shouldn't be there... so I want to check earlier than the hased password set.

Answer (score 0):

you can check like this

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && trim($_POST['password']) !="") {
       //run the code
}else{

}
```

Comment: this gives me back an error ..Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\wamp\www\unihalls3\includes\validation_functions

Comment: for some reason it actually seems to enter the if statement before submission so it doesn't get the proper values in the validation function file i created that basically just checks the values of the post form to have values for the required fields.